# What is the difference between UNIX and LINUX 'commands'? Difference in context of Commands

Tags: linux, unix, command

I have searched for answer of this question at many places on internet but none was satisfactory. Can anyone please tell me the main difference between a UNIX and LINUX OS. Is there any difference in commands of both?

Comment: Your question is unclear; What exactly do you mean by saying "Linux" and "Unix"?

Comment: Linux is Unix. Unix is not necessarily Linux.

Comment: @D4V1D Isn't it a Unix-**like**?

Comment: @MarounMaroun: Of course that Linux != Unix but rather Unix-like yeah. I kept it simple.

Comment: Linux is unix like .   But there are differences in commands,  especially between GNU and BSD versions (especially in options/flags)   Need more clarification on what you are looking for.  Also you should look into the posix standard as it might help

Comment: This question would be better suited for unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Check this: [Difference between unix and linux commands](http://superuser.com/questions/296174/difference-between-unix-and-linux-commands) and [what's the difference between linux and unix commands?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11417835/whats-the-difference-between-linux-and-unix-commands)

Answer (score 1):

Unix is a type of OS, linux is a specific kind of UNIX.

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/what-is-the-difference-between-linux-and-unix/

This should help!

My assumption is that you want to know about commands for different terminals. 
To know that, you would have to know you version and terminal. You can also pull up the man page for your terminal or look for online documentation.

The most common terminal is bash.

Comment: Linux is not a Unix.

Comment: Isn't Linux a subcategory/implementation of unix? Linux is Unix, but Unix isn't Linux?

Comment: Nope.  Linux descends from a basic rewrite of Minix.  It shares no ancestry with Unix.  It is not certified as Unix compliant.  Thus it's called 'Unix like'.  It sorta follows POSIX conventions, but many conventions shared by Unix derivatives such as Solaris( Oracle ) or BSD are not honored.

Comment: BSD interestingly IS a rewrite from source of the original AT&T Unix OS

Comment: Unix is now however a standard under the control and guidance of the Open Group and very much at odds with the Linux Foundations goals and leadership.

Answer (score 0):

UNIX tm. is a trademark of the Open Group:

http://www.opengroup.org/subjectareas/platform/unix

Linux is an operating system developed initially by Linus Torvalds.

Linux is not even POSIX certified much less a UNIX under Open Group Standards.  More because of cost of certification than anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Unix is the father of all modern OS, but its commercial.

Linux is the remake of unix with a GPL licence.

Comment: Linux was closer to a remake of Minix than any form of Unix.